# C# web browser alternative?

Tags: c#

I am looking for an alternative to web browser in C# that doesn't require being viewed, it needs to have navigation, the notice of when it's navigating and document loading has completed.

It also needs to be able to get and set elements by name, id, etc...

Is there such a way to do this without having webbrowser show up to the users?

Answer (score 3):

Use the .net classes that allow for retrieval of http information without UI controls, namely [HttpWebRequest](https://web.archive.org/web/20201129224046/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/demos/HttpWebRequestDemo1.aspx) or the simpler [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28VS.80%29.aspx).  HttpWebRequest has events that you can provide listeners for in order to execute actions as desired as specified times.  Here's a link to a page that exhibits an [example](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4637/retrieving-http-content-in-net/6/) of using such an event.

Answer (score 0):

Say what? Use the Web Browser control. You don't need to make it visible if you don't want to.

Answer (score 0):

See HtmlAgilityPack.  It will load documents and allows XPath expressions to find elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a browser control (for example you're doing a web scraper requiring execution of javascript, which you can't implement with a WebClient or HttpWebRequest), try [GeckoFX](http://www.geckofx.org), an open-source component which makes it easy to embed Mozilla Gecko (Firefox) into any .NET application.